# Parallel Operation of Transformers

Tags: transformer, parallel, three-phase

Can we connect Dz1 and Dz11 in parallel, in the case of transformer banks?

In the transformers industry, under the standards like IEC 60076 and IEEE C57.12, Dz1 is the designation for a three-phase transformer with the high voltage connected in Delta while the low voltage is connected in zig-zag. The number 1 denotes the phase shift between HV and LV side, which would be 30° (like the hand of a clock). The Dz11 is a similar connection, but due to different coils interconnection sequence, results in a phase shift between HV and LV of -30°.

Comment: What are Dz1 and Dz11?

Comment: Transformers of vector groups Dz1 and Dz11

Answer (score 2):

You might, but I wouldn't ;) as the circulating currents would be huge with different phase outputs.

Yd1/Dd1  Group - 3 (-30 degree)

Yd11/Dy11 Group - 4 (30 degree)

**D- stands for delta - Upper Case on HV side

y - stands for star- Lower Case on LV side**
**z - stands for zig-zag LV side.**

**Digits refer to 12 hour clock arm for LV side** with 30 deg phase shifts per hour in orientation.

**11** stands for arms of the clock at 11 position **means LV side leads HV side by 30 degrees.**

**1 means -30 deg.** or LV lags by 30 deg.